# A question on the big-O value of the complex integral especially in the number theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

My question is quite simple and elementary.

Let $A(x)=\sum_{1}^{x}a(n)$ and $\alpha(s)=\sum_{1}^{\infty}a(n)n^{-s}$. Then, as we know,
$$ A(x)= \int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{\alpha(s)}{s}x^sds$$
for some $\gamma$ such that $\alpha(\gamma)<\infty$.

Now the question comes, first, we denote $R_i$ $(i=1,2,3,...)$ as these residues of $\alpha(s)s^{-1}x^s$. And $R_0$ be the biggest residue among them. Then,
$$ A(x)=O(R_0)? $$
or are there counter examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a counterexample assuming the Riemann Hypothesis. Let $a(n):=\Lambda(n)-1$, where $\Lambda$ is the von Mangoldt function. Then $A(x)=\psi(x)-[x]$, where $\psi$ is the Chebyshev function, and $\alpha(s)=-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-\zeta(s)$, where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. So the biggest residue of $\alpha(s)s^{-1}x^s$ is of size $x^{1/2}$, yet we know that
$$ A(x)=\Omega(x^{1/2}\log\log\log x). $$
See Section 14.28 in Titchmarsh: The theory of the Riemann zeta-function.

Comment: Thank you. Then how about the case of finite number of residues?

Comment: @B.O.: If there are only finitely many residues, then under mild conditions (e.g. $\alpha(s)\ll |s|^{-\epsilon}$) the statement follows from the residue theorem and the fact that the residue at a point $s$ is of the form $x^s P_s(\log x)$, where $P_s$ is a polynomial with complex coefficients depending on $s$ (the degree of $P_s$ is one less than the order of the pole of $\alpha(w)/w$ at $w=s$).